# How to prevent performance bottleeck with polymer 1?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

**Environment**

Polymer 1

**Problem**: 
I use an Array with 35 objects. I create the list of elements (all the same) by a `dom-repeat`  template. It needs about 10 seconds to render all elements.

The whole browser is frozen until the process has finished.

**First try to fix it**
In my Custom element, I use a `dom-if` with the `restamp` property, because I expected that the HMTL render process will be faster but without success.

Can someone give me a hint, how I can improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [iron-list](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list) , it is what you are looking for

Here is a simple example, it can be used exacly like `dom-repeat`

```
<iron-list items="[[items]]">
<template>
  <div>
       [[item.name]]   
  </div>
</template>
```